# Rails : complex html <a> into link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink

How would I convert this link if I wanted to use the rails `<%= link_to %>` helper?

Here is my link :

> ```
> <a id="landing_link" href="#landing"><div id="headerlogo"></div></a>
> ```

Another question is that the link is an anchor link. In a link_to from another page, how would I link it to the page (eg. index) and then to the anchor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `do` block for link_to:

[The documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) ; their example:

```
<%= link_to(@profile) do %>
  <strong><%= @profile.name %></strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
<% end %>
# produces the following HTML:
<a href="/profiles/1">
  <strong>David</strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
</a>
```

**In your case**, `<a id="landing_link" href="#landing"><div id="headerlogo"></div></a>` **Becomes**:

```
<%= link_to '#landing', :id => 'landing_link' do %>
  <div id="headerlogo"></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= link_to "", "#landing", :id => 'landing_link' do %>
  <div id="headerlogo"></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a block to the link_to helper method :
(HAML)

```
= link_to("#landing", :id => "landing_link") do 
  .headerlogo
```

Comment: I've noticed , that you are using id for selecting elements of the DOM in your views . It is stated in the best Rails practices , that in views (stylesheets) DOM elements are selected by class and in .js (.coffee) - by ID .

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:div, '', :id=>'headerlogo'), '#landing', :id=>'landing_link' %>
```